# Read current Serilog's configuration

Tags: c#, serilog

Is there a property / method in Serilog where I could (programmatically) check the current configuration? (sinks, minimum level)

e.g. if have this config:

```cs
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.File("log.txt")
    .WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information)
    .CreateLogger();
```

How could I read this config later?

(In my case the config is dynamically created outside my application)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no reflective way to examine Serilog configuration.

Comment: That's unexpected! So if you like to alter the config, you need to recreate the whole config, isn't?

Comment: PS in NLog reading and changing the config could be done by `LogManager.Configuration`. So I was looking for that ;)

Comment: Yep, we do things differently :-)

Comment: That is really inconvenient! I have reqs to store settings in db after first load to prevent user messing with config file. I guess will have to store the whole json... Why it would be a problem to expose these configs read-only? In this case "differently"=drawback.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar for a log reader built into the app, so I worked around this by installing the [Serilog.Settings.AppSettings](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-appsettings) and read the config via the ConfigurationManager.

Since I have rolling enabled, I had to create a helper function to provide the actual filename of the log file.

```
public static string GetLogFileName()
{
        var filePathSetting = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("serilog:write-to:File.path");
        var rollingEnabled = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("serilog:write-to:File.rollingInterval");
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rollingEnabled))
        {
                if (rollingEnabled.Equals("Day"))
                {
                        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\.[a-z]+$)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                        var matches = regex.Matches(filePathSetting);
                        if (matches.Count > 0)
                        {
                                filePathSetting = filePathSetting.Replace(matches[0].Value, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + matches[0].Value);
                        }
                        return filePathSetting;
                }
        }

        return filePathSetting.ToString();
}
```